# Maintain Browser history or cache in Automation test Window

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver. When I test anything through automation then window doesn't contain any history, cache. My requirement is I want to maintain the previous history what was in normal chrome browser.

I googled it but not get any useful things. I am using chrome browser for testing and writing test case through java. I am opening normal mode of chrome not incognito or something like this.

Comment: Selenium, as default behaviour, will create a **new** browser profile each time it launches a new browser. Search for using specific profile.

Answer (score 0):

By default, ChromeDriver will create a new temporary profile for each session. You want to use a custom profile to keep the history.

You can use the 'user-data-dir' Chrome command-line switch to tell Chrome which profile to use:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Something like this should do the trick.